# Find Android app installed from googleplay or not

Tags: java, android, installation

Is there any way to find the origin of the current application at runtime, programmatically, to check if the application on device was downloaded from Google Play or installed via any other source?

Comment: What programming language does this relate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) to get the package name of application which installed the the application. The value is `com.android.vending` if the app was installed from Google Play.

You can check as shown below:

```
getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(getPackageName()).equals("com.android.vending")
```